# Nested SELECT vs JOIN performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following two tables in **PostgreSQL** database (simplified for the sake of example):

`article`

| **id** | **summary** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Article 1 |
| 2 | Article 2 |
| 3 | Article 3 |
| ... | ... |

`event`

| **id** | **article_id** | **eventtype_id** | **comment** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 1 | 4 | Comment 1 |
| 109 | 2 | 8 | Comment 2 |
| 110 | 3 | 4 | Comment 3 |
| ... |  |  | ... |

I would like to select only 1 `event` with `eventtype_id=4` for each `article`. The result should look like this:

| **article_id** | **article_summary** | **event_comment** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Article 1 | Comment 1 |
| 2 | Article 2 |  |
| 3 | Article 3 | Comment 3 |
| ... |  |  |

Which of these 2 queries (`Query 1` or `Query 2`) runs faster? Do they return the same result?

`Query1`:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id AS article_id,
    a.summary AS article_summary,
    evnt.comment AS event_comment
FROM 
    article a
LEFT JOIN
    event evnt ON evnt.article_id = a.id AND evnt.eventtype_id = 4;
```

`Query2`:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id AS article_id,
    a.summary AS article_summary,
    (
        SELECT
            evnt.comment
        FROM
            event evnt
        WHERE
            evnt.article_id = a.id AND
            evnt.eventtype_id = 4
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS event_comment
FROM 
    article a;
```

Comment: Use `explain (analyze, buffers)` - it will tell you which one will run faster. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Query2 is also a PITA when it comes to maintenance. Are you sure everybody in your (future) team can read and understand this within half a second? If not, that's when your code get new bugs. A LEFT JOIN is so simple, hard to miss that one. Also unclear why you have this question, you're the only one who can measure the difference in time. We don't have your data.

Comment: I found out that these 2 queries don't even return the same result. `Query 1` produces multiple rows for the same `article` if it has more than 1 associated `event` with `eventtype_id = 4`. `Query 2` produces only 1 row for each `article` even if it has more than 1 associated `event` with `eventtype_id = 4`.

Comment: The queries return different results. It doesn't make sense to compare their performance. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that queries are not the same, as you said in the comments, generally speaking, correlated queries are not considered suitable from a performance point of view. That's because these queries are applied row by row. They are usually helpful in some particular situations: [read this](https://bipp.io/sql-tutorial/advanced-sql/sql-correlated-subqueries/). However, even in those situations, it is a good practice to use them in an `exists` clause if possible, So that whenever it finds a row for the query it returns true.